# Protractor fails to find web-manager

Tags: npm, protractor, npm-install

I have protractor installed in project folder + web-manager (installed the same way).

The web-manager is started:

```
$npm-run webdriver-manager status

webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
- selenium standalone version available: 3.8.1 [last]
- chromedriver version available: 2.35 [last]
- geckodriver version available: v0.19.1 [last]
- IEDriverServer is not present
```

However, when I run protractor

```
$ npm-run protractor  conf.js

[15:22:12] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[15:22:12] E/local - Error code: 135
[15:22:12] E/local - Error message: No update-config.json found. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[15:22:12] E/local - Error: No update-config.json found. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
```

Here is my conf.js for protractor

```
exports.config = {

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'chrome',

  },

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['tests/common/*.js'],

};
```

How do I fix the config/run protrator?

Comment: did you run `webdriver-manager update`? thats what its telling you to run

Comment: @Gunderson, sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found a solution using gulp.
The config below allows to run webmanager-update, webmanager-start and proptractor on by one.

gulp.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'), 
    shell = require('gulp-shell'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'); // Webserver
    protractor = require('gulp-protractor').protractor,
    webdriver_standalone = require('gulp-protractor').webdriver_standalone,
    webdriver_update = require('gulp-protractor').webdriver_update;


gulp.task('webdriver_update', webdriver_update);
gulp.task('webdriver_standalone', webdriver_standalone);

gulp.task('e2e', ['webdriver_update'], function() {
  gulp.src(["tests/protractor/*.js"])
    .pipe(protractor({
        configFile: "protractor.conf.js",
        args: [
            //'--baseUrl', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
           // '--suite', 'login',
           // '--params.environment', 'test'
        ]
    }))
    .on('error', function(e) { throw e })
});
```

protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {

  seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar',

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'chrome',

  },

};
```

(using URL for selenium server is impotant)

Launch command:

```
gulp e2e
```

Comment: Gulp is a build tool. Most of us can use protractor normal without it, and if you not specify `seleniumServerJar`, `seleniumAddress`, and `directConnect` in protracot conf.js , protractor will start  selenium server at local using seleniumServerJar, and protractor will calcualte the jar file path before use it.  You not find the actual root cause of your problem, just find a bridge to another approch to fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

you need to run `npm-run webdriver-manager update` to install webdriver binary and selenium-standalon-server.jar if you never execute it, otherwise the command will update existed stuff.

After that, find `update-config.json` in `node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium`.

Its content should be like this:

```
{
    "chrome": {
        "last": "xxx\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\chromedriver_2.35.exe",
        "all": ["xxx\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\chromedriver_2.35.exe"]
    },
    "standalone": {
        "last": "xxx\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar",
        "all": ["xxx\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\selenium-server-standalone-3.9.0.jar"]
    },
    "gecko": {
        "last": "xxx\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\geckodriver-v0.19.1.exe",
        "all": ["xxx\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\geckodriver-v0.19.1.exe"]
    }
}
```

Then execute `node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager start` to see will success or fail.

FYI, you need JDK 8 installed to start webdriver-manager.

Comment: I have run this command. webdriver-manager has its binaries in local folder

Comment: Can you show your protractor conf file in question?  And i have a little question about `npm-run`, it's a standard cmd supplied by npm or it's an alias created by you.

Comment: conf file is present in main question, npm-run is a plugin that supports run from locally installed packages.

Comment: Can you add the output of your `npm-run webdriver-manager update --verbose` in your question